# Back Button takes you back too far

Tags: bug, android-app

1. I open the app
2. Enter Stack Overflow
3. Click *Show tags*
4. See list of tags
5. Search a tag
6. Select a tag
7. See the list of posts for that tag
8. Open a post and read it
9. Kick BACK-BUTTON

I am now back to step 4 and have to redo 5-7 every time. I would expect to get back to step 7.

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G900F

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (G900FXXU1CPFH)

Comment: I encountered the same bug, but I found that pressing back _twice_ takes me back to the list of questions in the tag. It's as if the two screens have been swapped in the back-stack somehow.

Comment: Every once in a while, the back button takes me back to step 7 as I expect. However it is intermittent and unreliable.